# Generate labels using xstring and \Makelowercase

Tags: cross-referencing, capitalization, xstring

I am trying to write a command that allows me to reference a subsection with a generated label.

The idea is that when I declare a step `\step{Long Name With Many Uppercase Letters}`, the generated label will be \label{step:long_name_with_many_uppercase_letters}.

I already found [Generate labels based on macro argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36906/generate-labels-based-on-macro-argument), but I fear the answer based on using `\@firstofone` does not work for my case.

My current approach is the following:

```
\makeatletter
% Step command
\newcounter{step}[section]
\setcounter{step}{0}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{%
  \subsection{#1} 
  \refstepcounter{step} 
  \label{step:\MakeLowercase{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{ }{\_}}}
}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, using the label command with other command inside gives me the following errors:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted \step{First Step}
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] \step{First Step}
```

If I remove the `\label` command, it works (but of course gives me warnings about undefined references).

A minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
% Step command
\newcounter{stepctr}[section]
\setcounter{stepctr}{0}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{%
  \subsection{#1} 
  \refstepcounter{stepctr} 
  \label{step:\MakeLowercase{\StrSubstitute[0]{#1}{ }{\_}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{My only chapter}

\section{A section where I reference steps}

I'd like to reference step number \ref{step:first_step} and \ref{step:third_step} here.

\section{A section where I define steps}

\step{First Step}

Foo.

\step{Second Step}

Bar.

\step{Third Step}

Whatever. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Useful Related Question: [Convert string to file name and use in `\href`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48305/convert-string-to-file-name-and-use-in-href)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to lowercase the argument of label, not have `\label` containing a lowercase command in its argument so invert the order of the expressions:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{xstring}


% Step command
\newcounter{stepctr}[section]
\setcounter{stepctr}{0}

\newcommand{\step}[1]{%
  \subsection{#1} %
  \refstepcounter{stepctr}%
  {\lccode`\ `\_\lowercase{\label{step:#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\chapter{My only chapter}

\section{A section where I reference steps}

I'd like to reference step number \ref{step:first_step} and \ref{step:third_step} here.

\section{A section where I define steps}

\step{First Step}

Foo.

\step{Second Step}

Bar.

\step{Third Step}

Whatever. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know it works this way around, but it does the trick.